# Papervision 3d hitTestObject doesn't work?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, papervision3d

I'm new to papervision 3d and I created two display objects in basic view.
Here's a part of the code :

```
...
_stick = new Cube(materials, 50, 5, 500);
_ball = new Sphere(new ColorMaterial(0xfc0000), 80);
```

In the `onRenderTick` method, I tried to check whether two objects are hitted

```
override protected function onRenderTick(event:Event=null):void {
    super.onRenderTick(event);
    _stick.rotationY = stage.mouseX / stage.width * 360;
    _stick.rotationX = stage.mouseY / stage.height * 360;

    if (stick.hitTestObject(this.ball)) {
        trace ("hit");
    }
}
```

However, `stick.hitTestObject` always returns false even if the stick really hits the ball as I see in the flash.

Any help is appreciated ~
Thanks!

Comment: just a note:  if you're new to PaperVision3D you should switch to Away3D or even start studying / using the Molehill (Flash Player 11) beta APIs for 3D.  PaperVision3D is, for all intents and purposes, dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long while back I worked around a similar issue by using an API I found somewhere in P3D that transforms from 3D to 2D (screen) coords. So I added a regular button on top of the 3D visuals, and each frame I moved the button to center on the screen location of the 3D hit area. But this only worked because I didn't need the hit area to transform - I never got "real" 3D hit areas to work in Papervision3D. And since that project is apparently orphaned, I wouldn't suggest spending a great deal of time on it if you can help it.

Comment: I have done quite a big project with Away3D recently and might i suggest you use away3D in combination with jiglib. Jiglib is a physics-library which is very capable of detecting hittests. I would look into it before you start however, because jiglib doesn't use the default primitives that away3D offers.